# Datagridview not selecting last row

Tags: c#

I am selecting records from a datagridview... I have got 5 rows in this datgridview and I am trying to select each and everyone of them by a click of a buton(NextrecordButton). This is working well but I am running into a problem the only 4 rows are selected and the last row isn't selected. is there anything am doing wrong in my code below:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (EmpCounter < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
   {
      TxtDisplay.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[EmpCounter]["Emp_Name"].ToString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is working well but I am running into a problem the only 4 rows
>   are selected and the last row isn't selected.

Because your check is checking till **second last row**

```
EmpCounter < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1
```

It should be:

```
EmpCounter < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

So your code should be:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EmpCounter < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
    {
        TxtDisplay.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[EmpCounter]["Emp_Name"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now running into another error with the previousRecordButton...        if (EmpCounter == dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count || questionCounter != 0)
            {
               
                TxtDisplay.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[EmpCounter]["Emp_Name"].ToString();} ...its says there is no row at position 4.. am i missing out anything again?

Comment: your check should be `if (EmpCounter < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count || questionCounter != 0)`